# slim php get route with parameter (user login system)

Tags: php, backbone.js, mysqli, execute, slim

I am trying to follow this: http://www.9bitstudios.com/2013/05/restful-backbone-js-implementation-using-slim-api/ and this http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/. I have this code so far - I have only just begun trying to understand the slim PHP framework:

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

 // GET route with parameter
$app->get('/users', function () use ($app) {

    // get all users
    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="backbone"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="Users"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    $mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "root", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM $tbl_name");
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->bind_result($namesie);

    while ($sql->fetch()) {
        echo json_encode($namesie);
    }

    $sql->close();
    $mysqli->close();
});

     // GET route with parameter
$app->get('/user/:username', function () use ($app) {

   $request = (array) json_decode($app->request()->getBody()); // WHAT IS THIS LINE DOING?
   var_dump($request);

   $host="localhost"; // Host name
   $password=""; // Mysql password
   $db_name="backbone"; // Database name
   $tbl_name="Users"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select databse.
   $mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "root", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

   $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=:username");
   var_dump($sql);
   $sql->execute();
   $sql->bind_result($dauser);
   echo json_encode($dauser);
});
```

The first route works as it should, displaying all the users like this: `"eamon""joe"`.

I did a `var_dump` on the `$request` variable in the second `GET` route (`/user/:username`) - it is an empty array...what is getting stored in this variable? Everything after `var_dump($request)` is just my attempt at getting the correct user based on username. Also `var_dump($sql)` prints out `bool(false)` meaning that the user is not being correctly found in the database. I have a database table called `Users` and I populated the database with two users: "joe" and "eamon". When I type `localhost/user/joe` into my browser, I get an error (along with the `var_dump`'s) saying:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`

I think I am getting this error because nothing has been stored in `$sql`. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am eventually going to be using backbone.js - I have been modeling the code in my routes after this project: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/. He declares the route and then uses a function like `getWine($id)` which is essentially what I am trying to implement - but for a user database instead. I am also using `mysqli` where as he is using `PDO` I think.

**UPDATE**

My code now looks like this:

```
$app->get('/user/:username', function ($username) use ($app) {

   $host="localhost"; // Host name
   $password=""; // Mysql password
   $db_name="backbone"; // Database name
   $tbl_name="Users"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select databse.
   $mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "root", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

   $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=?");

   $sql->bind_param("s",$username);
   $sql->execute();
   $sql->bind_result($profile);

   if($sql->fetch()) {
       echo json_encode($profile);
   }

   $sql->close();
   $mysqli->close();
});
```

When I type in `localhost/user/joe` ("joe" is a user that I inserted manually into the database) I get this error:

`mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement`

Isn't there only one field? The `username` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This accomplishes what I set out to do with the `/user/:username` route:

```
$app->get('/user/:username', function ($username) use ($app) {

   $host="localhost"; // Host name
   $password=""; // Mysql password
   $db_name="backbone"; // Database name
   $tbl_name="Users"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select databse.
   $mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "root", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

   $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, email FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=?");

   $sql->bind_param("s",$username);
   $sql->execute();
   $sql->bind_result($username1,$email);

   if($sql->fetch()) {
       echo $username1; 
       echo $email;
   }

   $sql->close();
   $mysqli->close();
});
```

To get rid of the last error I just needed to insert the names of the columns that I needed instead of using `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't actually use Slim and mysqli since a while but I think this should work:

```
$app->get('/user/:username', function ($username) use ($app) {

    ...

    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=?");
    $sql->bind_param($username);
    $sql->execute();
```

Comment: thanks! I'll update my question to reflect what I did with your code - I think we are on the right track. Got me to a new error - which you may understand...`mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement`

Comment: just figured it out, you were very close - bind_result did not like `SELECT * FROM`. I had to change it to `SELECT username, email FROM` which is actually better because I don't want to retrieve the password (the only other column in the table).

Comment: would you be able to help me with this? just a clarification really... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618716/slim-php-explanation-of-request-body-documentation