# slim php (explanation of "request body" documentation)

Tags: php, xml, json, http, slim

I am working with Slim PHP for the first time and I am trying to understand one of the concepts. In the slim PHP documentation, it states:

> Request Body
>
> Use the request object’s getBody() method to fetch the raw HTTP request body sent by the HTTP client. This is particularly useful for Slim application’s that consume JSON or XML requests.

```
<?php
$request = $app->request();
$body = $request->getBody();
```

My question is, what is "the raw HTTP request body"? Is it just a string of all the HTML in the body of the page? What format is it stored as? What would `echo $body` look like? If I do `var_dump($body)` I get `string(0)""`. How do I use it?

Comment: This is a REQUEST body, not the response, so normally there is no HTML in it. Get FireBug and play with the Network tab there

Comment: @astax i have firebug already...i went to the NET tab - I only see the GET request...when I click the arrow to view it I see the tabs `headers, response, cache, HTML`...what should I be looking for? What is the request body good for anyway?

Comment: That's the right place to look for, but GET requests don't have the body as all parameters are in the URL. Try submitting any form using POST and you'll see the data in "Post" tab

Comment: @astax cool...so what you are saying is this is a way to access form data from a POST request (for example)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll just make it an answer rather than comment...

Raw request data is what's submitted from the browser as a body of the POST request.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29#Use_for_submitting_web_forms

Technically it can be used to read the data from usual html forms, but this doesn't make much sense as PHP does this good enough and places everything into $_POST.

You may need to read raw data if you have some javascript that sends XML or JSON data, which is not natively accepted by PHP.

Comment: ah I see...I am also using backbone.js - which is what I think will eventually be sending JSON data to the server. For example...If I have a user object in backbone...and I need to get the username, password, email, etc., I would use `getBody()` from slim php - store it as an array - and then reference it like `$body[username]`?

Comment: Since the data is sent as JSON from Backbone I do believe that you need to convert it first like so: `$data = json_decode($request->getBody(), true);`

Answer (score 1):

The terms you ask for are defined in the [RFC2616: Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

For example, in particular what a Message (Request/Response) Body is: [4.3 Message Body](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.3).

If those RFCs are new to you, grab that one an read it from top to bottom and try to understand as much as possible. You'll start to see how those things in the internet work.

Also there is version 2.0 is in the pipe with some changes:

- [Hypertext Transfer Protocol version 2.0 (Draft 04)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-04)

Just in case you're interested.